# Xero oAuth 2 authorisation

Tags: c#, xero-api

I have a .net core web API server that I connect to from a mobile application. The server creates an invoice on Xero and sends the user an email etc...

I have been using oAuth 1 with no issues, but now need to switch to oAuth 2. As there is no front end-user on the API server, can this still be accomplished?

All the documentation I read, seems to need a manual login to grant authorization and get an access token?

I was using the XeroApi settings in my appsettings.json file with a pfx certificate and a private app.

I am using the C# SDK

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a user from the Xero organisation to go through the [OAuth2.0 flow](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow) at least once to retrieve an access token. If you request the `offline_access` scope during this flow, you'll receive a refresh token as well; this will enable you to refresh the access token from your web server on an ongoing basis, without user intervention.

So yep, you'll need a manual login at least once, but as long as you request & retain the refresh token from that initial flow, once should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have done this and am able to achieve my requirements.